# Stringency of DocuSign Certification

Tags: docusignapi

From the DocuSign "API Requirements Information":

> [Y]our API certification review involves verifying that you do not exceed 1 status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes for polling compliance for the following methods: ...
>
> REST API: GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

How stringent are these requirements? If 99% of my users will only make 1 status request, but a few (who sign up around midnight) will make 2 requests in close proximity to each other, will my API access be revoked? How risky is this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be answered by the company's support department. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: I'd typically agree, except that I already asked this question to the company's support department, and they asked me to put it on Stack Overflow. Of course, this is the company's fault, not SO's. But I'm curious about what other users of the DocuSign API have done in this predicament. I hope I'm not the only one!

Comment: Ideally you'd either 1) cache these results so that you only poll on a schedule or 2) you'd use Connect to receive updates that you'd store.

Comment: You should email this question and any others related to API Certifications for DocuSign to apicertifications@docusign.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guidelines mean that you should not allow end users to continously click through to docusign to fetch latest status.

As Jeff says in the comments, you should use the Connect api, or per-envelope callback, or cache the status responses, making an actual request to docusign no more than once every 15 minutes per envelope.

Maximum polling frequency and status architecture is one of the key issues that the certification process seeks to investigate.

You could also disable your "status" button for 15 minutes after a request.  But that wouldn't be a good ux. Better to effectively disable it via a 15 minute cache.  - - like the close button on elevators.

**Added**

The per-envelope callback parameter is [eventNotification](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=eventNotification).

Comment: I'm familiar with the Connect API, and with caching the response. But what  do you mean by a "per-envelope callback"?