# Which DocuSign API requests are frequency-limited?

Tags: docusignapi

From the DocuSign "API Requirements Information":

```
>[Y]our API certification review involves verifying that you do not exceed 1 status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes for polling compliance for the following methods: ...
>REST API: GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

Is this the only REST endpoint that is limited? Am I permitted to make requests to other endpoints (like: `GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`) with more frequency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904113/stringency-of-docusign-certification

Comment: I'm the author of that question you linked. I think this is a different question, albeit about the same API endpoint. Merging the questions would be worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) -> [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) and under the Certification Docs section see the PDF titled **"Security & Design Requirements"**

From the document:

`DocuSign has imposed a default 1,000 API call per hour limit for each account. This limit ensures resource availability for all account holders, while reducing the chances of a denial of service (DOS) attack. Exceeding this limit will result in your API calls receiving an exception for up to 60 minutes. However, the call limit is the default setting and not a service limitation. When evaluating your integration, if you feel the API call per hour limit will restrict your application’s usage based on anticipated volumes, please contact DocuSign to discuss further options. Additionally, your API certification review involves verifying that you do not exceed 1 status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes for polling compliance for the following methods:`

**SOAP API**: `RequestStatus, RequestStatusEx, RequestStatuses, RequestStatusesEx, RequestPDF and RequestDocumentPDFs.`

**REST API**: `GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`

According the Certification doc those are the only restricted endpoints for each API.